# Android Studio give error 401 with Laravel login Api

Tags: java, android, laravel

I had an easy question, I am writing api in laravel and I will put it in my android application, but although the register part and logout part work correctly, when I check from postman in the login section, it takes the token and logs in, but when we come to the application, I get a 401 error when logging in, I wonder why? My login code is in the controller like this:

```
$credentials = $request->validate([
‘email’=>‘required|email’,
‘password’=>‘required’
]);
if(Auth::attempt($credentials)){
$user=Auth::user();
$token=md5(time()).‘.’.md5($request->email);
$user->forceFill([
‘api_token’=>$token,
])->save();
return response()->json([
‘token’=>$token
]);

   }
   return response()->json(['message'=>'The provided credentials do not match our records'],401);
}
```

It gives correct in Postman, it doesn't cause any problem, but I register in the application. It's not a problem. It gives 401 at login, I wonder why? My code in the application is as follows:

```
private void sendLogin() {
JSONObject params= new JSONObject();
try {
params.put(“email”,email);
params.put(“password”,password);

    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    String data = params.toString();
    String url = getString(R.string.api_server)+"/login";
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Http http = new Http(LoginActivity.this,url);
            http.setMethod("POST");
            http.setData(data);
            http.send();
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Integer code = http.getStatusCode();
                    if(code == 200){
                        try{
                            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(http.getResponse());
                            String token = response.getString("token");
                            localStorage.setToken(token);
                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,UserActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            finish();
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else if(code ==422){
                        try{
                           JSONObject response = new JSONObject(http.getResponse());
                           String msg = response.getString("message");
                           alertFail(msg);
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else if(code == 401){
                        try{
                            JSONObject response = new JSONObject(http.getResponse());
                            String msg = response.getString("message");
                            alertFail(msg);
                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error"+code,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
}
```

I'll be happy if you can help me

Answer (score 0):

send this with headers

```
["Accept"] = "application/json";
["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
["withCredentials"] = true;
```

and in env laravel add this (values are just for example)

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=.localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost,127.0.0.1
```